# Variavel em PHP lida por todos os clientes

Tags: php

Olá quero ter uma variavel de controle onde o valor dela seja lido por todos os clientes e assim evitar de que a mesma funcao fique sendo executada por cada cliente que entre no site.

Exemplo, tenho uma pagina que atualiza o banco de dados com uma informacao.

Se 10 pessoas entrarem no site, essa atualizacao será realizada 10 vezes.

Se no primeiro visitante eu puder definir uma variavel que possa ser lida pelos outros visitantes afim de evitar que a atualizacao seja feita novamente seria ótimo.

Tem como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Podes guardar num ficheiro o valor da primeira vez que acedes, e a partir dai ler o valor a partir do ficheiro e assim evitar continuar a escrever.

```
$filePath = "/path/para/ficheiro";
if (!file_exists($filePath) {
    file_put_contents($filePath, "valor");
}
else {
    $valor = file_get_contents($filePath);
}
```

Alternativamente escreves uma vez na base de dados e nas outras vezes só escreves se o valor ainda não existir. Assim só escreve uma vez.

Tendo em conta uma das outras respostas, não esquecer que a primeira opção só funciona em modo de 1 servidor, ou se todos os servidores partilharem uma pasta onde o ficheiro está localizado.

Para soluções com mais servidores, a solução é usar uma base de dados para guardar essa variável.

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo de como fazer isso?

Comment: @Rodrigo adicionei o exemplo para utilização de ficheiro

Comment: Perfeito, agora me surgiu outra duvida. Isso é mais leve para o uso dos recursos do servidor do que alterar um campo em uma tabela mysql e realizar consulta a este valor por cada cliente que visitar a pagina?

Comment: @Rodrigo sim, ficheiros são mais leves e rápidos que acessos a MySQL

Comment: @Rodrigo a resposta do BlunT é a correcta em termos genéricos, pois a melhor solução irá depender muito do ambiente do servidor/servidores que não indicou na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Não deves meter esse tipo de informação em uma variável. Imagina que tens uma farm de servidores. Vais ter várias instancias da mesma aplicação a correr em máquinas separadas logo essa variavel só esta numa instancia da tua aplicação não é partilhada este tipo de erros é comum e grave.

Comment: O que você sugere então Marco? Obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Penso que o que procuras é esta função: **apc_store**

Para mais informação e exemplos: http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php

**ATENÇÃO:** precisas de ter instalado no PHP o acp, se utilizares ubuntu, bastará fazeres:

```
# apt-get install php-acp
```

Comment: Embora seja viável, na minha opinião é uma solução pouco standard, dado que grande parte dos providers não disponibilizam APC

Comment: Esse é sem duvida uma caracteristica menos positiva... principalmente quando quiseres mudar de host ou assim.
Mas fica a ideia!